# Aliases for temporary registers

Tags: registers

In a package I'm working on I have several macros which require the use of a register temporarily to figure something out before the macro knows what to print (usually its a length or glue which needs to be mathematically manipulated or checked against something else).  Currently I'm putting a `\new...` command right before these temporary registers get used for the first time to create them, but I've come to understand that this isn't a good practice because register allocation is a global phenomena in TeX and thus if a macro which contains a `\new...` command is called multiple times, it will reserve multiple registers (potentially leading to TeX running out in large documents).

I'd like, therefore, to move the `\new...` commands out of the macros to base level of the package.  I'd also like to limit the number of such registers, allowing TeX to reuse them.  The problem is that in my functions, its my practice to give these registers useful names that allow someone reading the code to tell what the register is being used for (i.e. the register might be called `\distanceatob` not simply `\tempdistance`).  Thus if I simply move the `\new...` commands I end up with quite the collection of registers.

Is there any way within a macro to tell TeX to use a particular reserved register but to refer to it under a different name than the one in the `\new...` command?

Comment: Does the `\let` 'mechanism' not work for registers? Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Using such aliases is possible with `\let`, but this opens the possibility of misusing them: if `\a` and `\b` are let to register `\x`, then using both `\a` and `\b` in the same macro would result in a disaster. In several cases, a macro is as useful as a register, depending on how you want to use them.

Comment: That was exactly what I did in the version of the code I posted as an answer to your previous question.

Comment: see `\ifrubber% if we have a rubber allowed length we create a temporary skip
        \let\gre@temp\gre@temp@skip
    \else% otherwise we create a temporary dimen
        \let\gre@temp\gre@temp@dimen
    \fi%`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I missed that change.  I'll go back and take a closer look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define

```
\newdimen\zzzz
```

at the top level and then locally use

```
   \let\SensibleNameOne=\zzzz
   ...
   \SensibleNameOne=3in
   ...
   \let\SensibleNameTwo=\zzzz
   ...
   \SensibleNameTwo=4in
   ...
```

But if you do this you have to be careful and preferably not alias the names in the same scope  as if you do exactly as above `\SensibleNameOne` will have the value of 4in as it means the same as `\SensibleNameTwo`.

This is most useful in classic TeX where you only have 256 registers, in etex where there are 32768, or luatex where there are twice that, it is less of an issue.

It is even possible to avoid allocating any registers if you are only going to use them in a local scope that you control, and you know that another local context can not be nested.

`graphics` package needs a bunch of registers for saving results of measuremnts and trigonometry calculations, it does

```
\let\Grot@height\@ovxx
\let\Grot@left\@ovyy
\let\Grot@right\@ovdx
\let\Grot@depth\@ovdy
\let\Grot@l\@ovro
\let\Grot@r\@ovri
\let\Grot@h\@xdim
\let\Grot@d\@ydim
\let\Grot@x\@linelen
\let\Grot@y\@dashdim
```

which "borrows" some registers allocated within the format for picture mode. If you are doing this (and I don't really advise it) then you need to make sure that all groups are controlled such that the registers have the right meaning at the right time, so here for example despite the fact that these registers are overloaded the grouping ensures that you can nest a `picture` environment of a `\rotatebox` and put a rotated box in a `picture` environment  and the registers always have the intended values at the intended time. `\rotatebox` setting  `\Grot@y` will never affect the length of the dashes in picture mode, even though it's (ab)using `\@dashdim`.

Comment: With `\usepackage{etex}` (and soon even without it), you'll have enough registers to have to care about one or two of them, no? So let's just be semantic :-)

Comment: @yo' excellent package that, who wrote it:-) but even with etex allocation it will still be bad practice to put an allocation in a macro that is re-used, it just takes longer for the failure.

Comment: I'm moving in the direction of being as semantic as possible without reallocating registers all the time.  The package I'm working on typesets Gregorian chant and these temporary registers are used primarily to align the text and notes in each syllable.  As a result, a long score can easily need to do these calculations over 100 times.  A complete book of chant could have over 1000 scores in it, so even LuaLaTeX (which the package requires) would run out of registers in the really big cases.